# latex \right] not show up in pdf

Tags: math-mode

The following is a piece of LaTeX code displaying a function. But in the PDF file generated , the right bracket "]", which is last thing in the equation, does not show up. However, if I replace "\right]" with just "]", then the right bracket show up. But I want the larger right bracket "\right]", not the small one "]".
This code has another problem: the two fractions have different sizes! The first fraction is taller and the second fraction is shorter. The second fraction turns out to have smaller font size on the PDF, which I do not like.

Could anyone please point out to me how I can insert a large right bracket and have all the fractions use the same font size as those non-fractions (i.e. fractions should be twice the height as those non-fraction numbers)?

```
$\textbf{E} = E_0 \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{\hat{x}} cos(kz-\omega t) + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{\hat{y}} cos\left(kz-\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]$
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me (except I had to replace `\textbf` with `\mathbf` around the `\hat`s). What LaTeX distribution are you using? Perhaps something is wrong with it?

Comment: If you use `\cos` (instead of without the slash) it's treated as a proper function name, not three variables named `c`, `o`, and `s`.

Comment: You do also realize that `cos(x + pi/2) = -sin(x)`?  :)

Comment: Change all the \textbf to \bf, then the right ] will show up and the second fraction will be in display mode rather than text mode.

Comment: @"ex-officemate of test" whatever else, _don't_ compound the problem changing a current command for a deprecated one (`\bf`); someone else has correctly pointed out that `\mathbf` should be used in place of `\textbf` -- substituting a maths-mode command for a text-mode command.

Comment: That input produces *many* syntax errors and the missing bracket is a by-product of them. Don't overlook error messages from the compiler.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want

```
$\mathbf{E} = E_0 \bigl[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mathbf{\hat{x}} \cos(kz-\omega t)
  + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \mathbf{\hat{y}} \cos(kz-\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2})\bigr]$
```

For getting a variable in boldface the correct way is to say `\mathbf` (which works also with accents such as `\hat`).

Instead of `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` you can say `\left[` and `\right]`, it depends on personal taste: I feel that the latter gives too high brackets.

For the "cosine function" the right input is `\cos`.

Comment: is there a reason that `\bigr[` and `\bigl]` are opposite to what one would expect?

Comment: @barbarabeeton A mistake? :)